# What would be the best way to pass a value to a modal?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using [Mobile Angular UI](http://mobileangularui.com/) and cannot figure out how to pass a value to a modal.

// Button

This button is inside of an `ng-repeat="item in vm.items"` and needs `item` to be somehow passed to the modal.

```
<button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" ui-turn-on="modal">Remove</button>
```

// Modal

```
  <div class="modal scrollable-content section" ui-if='modal' ui-state='modal'>
    <div class="modal-backdrop in"></div>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form role="form" name="note" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button class="close" 
                  ui-turn-off="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure?</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Are you sure you'd like to remove this item?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button ui-turn-off="modal" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" ng-click="vm.remove(item); Ui.turnOff('modal')" class="btn btn-primary">Remove</button>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It might help if you post a fiddle of what you have.

Comment: How are you opening the modal?

Comment: @PSL, `ui-turn-on="modal"` in the button.  micafe has a good idea. I can set a variable on the $scope when the button is clicked.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 on button click, you also call a function like

 <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" ui-turn-on="modal" 
 ng-click="setItemID(item.itemID)">Remove</button> 

 And then create the setItemID(itemID) function into the angularjs controller
 and put the itemID into a scope variable.

 When user will click on the remove button, the setItemID function will be
 called and the itemId will be assigned into the scope. Now at the time when
 user click "Yes i want to remove this item", then use that defined itemID.
 Hope you get your solution. If still have any problem then lets comment.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write an html tag (item) attribute with a value and read the value

var id = item.attributes['data-id'].value;